# How does this <td> overflow the <table>?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am adding a next and previous button to a `<td>` that contains an `asp:DropDownList`.
When I do this the `<td>` overflows the width of the table.

Code Snippet (Edited to include entire table to avoid confusion):

```
<table class="DataEntry" border="1">
  <caption>Adding New Record</caption>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col" colspan="3">&nbsp;&nbsp;Add To Invoice&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" >
     <div style="white-space:nowrap;">
       <asp:ImageButton ID="PreviousInvoiceAdding" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Previous16x16.png" OnClick="PreviousInvoice_Click" ToolTip="Previous" />
       <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListInvoice" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="rMidiEntrySelect" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListInvoice_SelectedIndexChanged" />
       <asp:ImageButton ID="NextInvoiceAdding" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Next16x16.png" OnClick="NextInvoice_Click" ToolTip="Next" />
     </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;&nbsp;Cost&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col" colspan="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Date Purchased&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <asp:TextBox ID="Cost" runat="server" CssClass="rMidiEntryText" MaxLength="8"/>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div style="text-align: center">
         <asp:Label ID="DatePurchased" runat="server" class="rMidiEntryLabel"/>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;&nbsp;Volume Type&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;&nbsp;Measurement&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;&nbsp;Units&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <select ID="SelectVolumeType" name="Measurement" runat="server" class="rMidiEntrySelect" disabled >
           <option value="0">Liquid</option>
           <option value="1">Weight</option>
       </select>
    </td>
    <td>
       <asp:DropDownList  ID="SelectMeasurement" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="rMidiEntrySelect" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Units" runat="server" CssClass="rMidiEntryText" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col" colspan="3">&nbsp;&nbsp;Invoice Reference&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <asp:TextBox ID="InvoiceRef" runat="server" CssClass="rMidiEntryText" MaxLength="100"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Result:

[image: Rendered table]

The `class="DataEntry"` on the `<table>` and the `CssClass="rMidiEntrySelect"` on the `asp:DropDownList` are not causing any issues (as I have stripped them out to verify).

I have tried a few variations such as `<td colspan="3" style="white-space:nowrap;">` without the `<div>` with no luck.

Without the Previous and Next buttons:

```html
<table class="DataEntry" border="1">
  <caption>Adding New Record</caption>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col" colspan="3">&nbsp;&nbsp;Add To Invoice&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" >
      <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListInvoice" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="rMidiEntrySelect" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListInvoice_SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  .
  .
  .
</table>
```

[image: Rendered table without buttons]

Relevant CSS As Requested:

```css
table.DataEntry {
border-color: #00274C;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-collapse: collapse;
padding: 4px; 
color: white;
font-size: 10pt;
}

table.DataEntry caption {
background-color: #004280;
color: #FFD11A;/* #FFCB05;*/
border-color: #00274C;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-collapse: collapse;
padding: 4px;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 12pt;
white-space: nowrap;
text-decoration: underline;
text-underline-position: under;
text-align:center; 
caption-side: top;
vertical-align: top;
}

table.DataEntry th {
background-color: #00274C;
color: #FFCB05;
text-align:center; 
}

.rMidiEntryLabel {
width: 100%;
color: white;
background-color: black; 
padding-left: 4px;  
padding-right: 2px;
border-style: none;
text-align: center !important;
}

.rMidiEntryText {
width: 100%;
color: white;
background-color: black; 
padding-left: 4px;  
padding-right: 2px;
border-style: none;
text-align: center !important;
}

.rMidiEntrySelect {
width: 100%;
color: white;
background-color: black; 
padding-left: 4px;  
padding-right: 2px;
text-align: center !important;
}
```

The rest of the CSS is all bootstrap (which I do not believe is relevant).

The HTML Output as requested (Looks just fine to me):

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="3" >
   <div style="white-space:nowrap;">
     <input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$PreviousInvoiceAdding" id="MainContent_PreviousInvoiceAdding" title="Previous" src="Images/Previous16x16.png" />
     <select name="ctl00$MainContent$DropDownListInvoice" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$MainContent$DropDownListInvoice\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="MainContent_DropDownListInvoice" class="rMidiEntrySelect">
  <option selected="selected" value="ee29b399-34a7-4024-819d-790c9903d4b5~12/11/2023 12:00:00 PM">PayPal: 53S99726XA966511X Brian Garmins Jr.</option>
  <option value="3013ce76-18e3-4458-b4c0-1c17ca46a503~11/28/2023 12:00:00 PM">PayPal: 6F945766E4687834E Nelson Laquindanum</option>
  <option value="722137b5-3201-408a-bd90-9cac6d72829f~11/23/2023 12:00:00 PM">Amazon 111-3584319-8686651</option>
  <option value="4aee9017-8930-4028-ad3f-ff1c494e91bb~10/30/2023 12:00:00 PM">PayPal: 8FL63970TJ5988418 Shake Ums</option>
  <option value="b9995175-f516-4366-9b30-32f03830c724~10/25/2023 12:00:00 PM">PayPal: 4WR12564FW882444X Brett Shumock</option>
  <option value="ec0f668b-1fe7-4424-9264-fc0825b9e999~10/18/2023 12:00:00 PM">PayPal: 6L091961CE7545104 Brandon Reigert</option>
  
  </select>
     <input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$NextInvoiceAdding" id="MainContent_NextInvoiceAdding" title="Next" src="Images/Next16x16.png" />
   </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I am asking my question is due to the results I am seeing which seems to break basic HTML rules.
A TD is a child of a TR.
A TR is a child of TABLE.
The TABLE is the 'container' which contains everything.
Nothing within the TABLE should be able to exceed the boundaries of the TABLE.

Comment: Why do you have `colspan="3"` on there? That makes the `td`/`th` element span across 3 columns, and you only have 1.

Comment: @DavidG from the images it looks like subsequent rows do have 3 separate tds. Also in my experience colspan that is larger than needed is ignored by all browsers (no extra or phantom tds are inserted).

Comment: I believe that `asp:DropDownList` generates an HTML `<select>` element, but otherwise my memory is a bit vague. Please post what the generated HTML of that part looks like + all CSS that is applied to it.

Comment: most likely your page is not generating 3 columns (td) and as a result, the colspan="3" is causing it to add a third column at the end. Please edit your post to include the mark up for that entire table. If you right click on the table and inspect it, hovering over your `<table>` tag should highlight the entire table if that is the case.

Comment: The ... are intended to represent the continuation of the code. The table in fact has three columns. 'Add To Invoice and my drop down are colspan="3'. next row cost is colspan 1, datepurchased is colspan='2' and so on,

Comment: Edited: Added full table, CSS, Output HTML for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't tell you why, exactly, but it's definitely the `width: 100%` on the `DropDownListInvoice` that's causing the overflow, when combined with the `white-space:nowrap;` rule of the container div.

Running in a jsFiddle, with those rules:

[image: Not the table you're looking for...]

but remove those two rules:

[image: It's a-ok!]

I suspect it has to do with how the browser calculates element width.

- table takes up 100% width of it's parent
- table row takes up 100% width of it's parent table
- table data cell takes up 100% width of it's parent table row (since it's the only cell in this row and has a column-span that covers the whole row)
- inputs are inline, so they only take up as much width as necessary
- select takes up 100% width of it's parent cell

Normally that last bit would be fine - the inputs and select would stack up. The no-wrap rule, though, forces them to be in a single line of content, which also causes them to overflow the containing div.

You can play around with this jsFiddle, which shows that it's the form elements which are overflowing: https://jsfiddle.net/p8oqfw7h/1/

If you're trying to accomplish the last image regardless of content, you'll probably want to play around with flex-box. I don't have a solution at the moment that would show how to implement that, though it shouldn't be too difficult if you're familiar with flex-box.

Comment: Tieson is correct width: 100% on the DropDownListInvoice. I removed the width: 100% from the DropDown and added it to the <div>.  Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

I just put display:flex in this div tag: `<div style="white-space:nowrap;display: flex;">`

```css
table.DataEntry {
border-color: #00274C;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-collapse: collapse;
padding: 4px; 
color: white;
font-size: 10pt;
}

table.DataEntry caption {
background-color: #004280;
color: #FFD11A;/* #FFCB05;*/
border-color: #00274C;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-collapse: collapse;
padding: 4px;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 12pt;
white-space: nowrap;
text-decoration: underline;
text-underline-position: under;
text-align:center; 
caption-side: top;
vertical-align: top;
}

table.DataEntry th {
background-color: #00274C;
color: #FFCB05;
text-align:center; 
}

.rMidiEntryLabel {
width: 100%;
color: white;
background-color: black; 
padding-left: 4px;  
padding-right: 2px;
border-style: none;
text-align: center !important;
}

.rMidiEntryText {
width: 100%;
color: white;
background-color: black; 
padding-left: 4px;  
padding-right: 2px;
border-style: none;
text-align: center !important;
}

.rMidiEntrySelect {
width: 100%;
color: white;
background-color: black; 
padding-left: 4px;  
padding-right: 2px;
text-align: center !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="DataEntry" border="1">
    <caption>Adding New Record</caption>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" colspan="3">&nbsp;&nbsp;Add To Invoice&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" >
        <div style="white-space:nowrap;display: flex;">
          <input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$PreviousInvoiceAdding" id="MainContent_PreviousInvoiceAdding" title="Previous" src="Images/Previous16x16.png" />
            <select name="ctl00$MainContent$DropDownListInvoice" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$MainContent$DropDownListInvoice\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="MainContent_DropDownListInvoice" class="rMidiEntrySelect">
              <option selected="selected" value="ee29b399-34a7-4024-819d-790c9903d4b5~12/11/2023 12:00:00 PM">PayPal: 53S99726XA966511X Brian Garmins Jr.</option>
              <option value="3013ce76-18e3-4458-b4c0-1c17ca46a503~11/28/2023 12:00:00 PM">PayPal: 6F945766E4687834E Nelson Laquindanum</option>
              <option value="722137b5-3201-408a-bd90-9cac6d72829f~11/23/2023 12:00:00 PM">Amazon 111-3584319-8686651</option>
              <option value="4aee9017-8930-4028-ad3f-ff1c494e91bb~10/30/2023 12:00:00 PM">PayPal: 8FL63970TJ5988418 Shake Ums</option>
              <option value="b9995175-f516-4366-9b30-32f03830c724~10/25/2023 12:00:00 PM">PayPal: 4WR12564FW882444X Brett Shumock</option>
              <option value="ec0f668b-1fe7-4424-9264-fc0825b9e999~10/18/2023 12:00:00 PM">PayPal: 6L091961CE7545104 Brandon Reigert</option>       
            </select>
          <input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$NextInvoiceAdding" id="MainContent_NextInvoiceAdding" title="Next" src="Images/Next16x16.png" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">&nbsp;&nbsp;Cost&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
      <th scope="col" colspan="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Date Purchased&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <asp:TextBox ID="Cost" runat="server" CssClass="rMidiEntryText" MaxLength="8"/>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div style="text-align: center">
           <asp:Label ID="DatePurchased" runat="server" class="rMidiEntryLabel"/>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">&nbsp;&nbsp;Volume Type&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
      <th scope="col">&nbsp;&nbsp;Measurement&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
      <th scope="col">&nbsp;&nbsp;Units&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <select ID="SelectVolumeType" name="Measurement" runat="server" class="rMidiEntrySelect" disabled >
             <option value="0">Liquid</option>
             <option value="1">Weight</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>
         <asp:DropDownList  ID="SelectMeasurement" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="rMidiEntrySelect" />
      </td>
      <td>
          <asp:TextBox ID="Units" runat="server" CssClass="rMidiEntryText" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" colspan="3">&nbsp;&nbsp;Invoice Reference&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
          <asp:TextBox ID="InvoiceRef" runat="server" CssClass="rMidiEntryText" MaxLength="100"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: How does this help?

Comment: Thanks Mahesh. This is a .NET 'Webpage' (.aspx, .aspx.cs). The table is being filled by a database record; the drop down is being filled by another database query. Of course, containing the previous and next buttons in their own TD's is an answer to prevent the over-flow I am seeing, but it simply does not look as clean as I would like it to.

Comment: I have made some changes please check the code again...